# Importing Function From Unmanaged DLL in C# Application

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, dllimport, dll

I need to import a function that I wrote in C++, and is now compiled into a DLL, into my C# application.  Everything builds without errors or warnings, but when I step through the code the first function call into the DLL throws an `Exception` with a message of "Unable to find an entry point named 'CreateScanEngine" in DLL 'WMIQuery.dll'."  The function is declared like so in my C# application:

```
internal static class WMIQuery
{
    [DllImport("WMIQuery.dll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern void CreateScanEngine();
}
```

Dependency Walker shows the function there in the DLL as such:

> Ordinal: 1(0x0001)
>   Hint: 0(0x0000)
>   Function ^: void CreateScanEngine(void)
>   Entry Point: 0x00001860

Dependency Walker also shows these errors/warnings for the DLL:

> Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
>   Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
>   Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Will this make a difference?  Also, I tried adding the DLL as a reference to the C# project, and I got this error:

> A reference to [my DLL] could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use Dependency Walker, it unmangles the exported name of the function and doesn't tell you the real export name.  Note that it is smart enough to see that it takes no arguments and has no return value.  It can only do this if it sees the name as decorated by the C++ compiler.

Use Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to see the real name.  It ought to be "?CreateScanEngine@@YGXXZ", use the EntryPoint property in the [DllImport] attribute.   You may also want to declare the function with extern "C" so this name mangling doesn't happen.

Comment: Dependency Walker has an option to turn off name mangling. Toolbar icon for that option has C++ written on it.

Comment: I tried adding the `extern "C"` to remove the mangling, as you suggested, but now I'm getting a compiler warning: `warning C4297: 'CreateScanEngine' : function assumed not to throw an exception but does. The function is extern "C" and /EHc was specified.`  What is /EHc and what would be the proper way to clear this warning?  Thanks.

Comment: Nice warning.  You should not throw an exception in a function that you export.  There will be nobody to catch that exception, the managed code will bomb with an exception message that nobody will know how to troubleshoot because it doesn't contain any decent information.  If you want to ignore this and shut the compiler up then Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Enable C++ Exceptions = /EHa.

Answer (score 1):

How are you declaring CreateScanEngine in your C++ code?

Try changing to:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall CreateScanEngine();
```

Comment: I don't think it's needed but I added it

Comment: I tried adding the `extern "C"` to remove the mangling, but now I'm getting a compiler warning: `warning C4297: 'CreateScanEngine' : function assumed not to throw an exception but does. The function is extern "C" and /EHc was specified.`  What is /EHc and what would be the proper way to clear this warning?  Thanks.

Comment: @Jim: Remove the exception throwing :)